# UIScrollView not passing touches to subviews?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a scrollview, I embed 3 controllers inside this scrollView in storyboard, and page between them horizontally.

content size of the scrollview is (scrollViewWith * numberOfControllers , scrollViewHeight)

scrollview appears and I am able to scroll horizontally thought the views, but the views don't detect any touch. (The controllers embedded have collectionViews inside them)

I implemented touchesBegin in one of the controllers, and it's never getting called.

Any idea what could cause the scrollview not to pass touches to subviews?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer to why touch events aren't making it to the collection views, but it sounds like you're reimplementing `UIPageViewController` with the `transitionStyle` set to `.Scroll`. Maybe consider using that instead?

Comment: UIPageViewController won't work because I have a tab bar on top of the scrollview that suppose to interact with the controllers, plus custom animations as the result of scrolling between pages

Comment: Sounds good. It's not common control that every knows about so I thought I'd try and save you some pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

when adding views to a controller through embedded segue, the view of the viewController is not added directly inside of the main view, but it's embedded in another container view before being added to the main view

```
ViewControllerView->EmbedView->EmbededViewControllerView
```

So I ended up removing them both, and manually add the view of the viewControllers to the scrollView

Answer (score -1):

what kinds of view's you have inside every page of the UIScrollView?

You can add anything there, for example a UICollectionView, and the only way to prevent to not pass touches inside is having the UIScrollView set as:

```
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: "the only way to prevent to not pass touches inside is having the UIScrollView set as ..." that's not true, you could override hitTest and limit touches.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's another way :), but did you fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, took me a full day on such stupid issue. I posted the answer below, it was the containerView in storyboard that was causing the problem :(